# Join only in one implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I have my model like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "resourceType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Resource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    Long id;

    String foo;
}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class NetworkResource extends Resource { 
    String bar;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public class URL extends NetworkResource {
     String url;
}
```

I put the discrimination value in all the more specific implementations, because I dont want to join all tables that extends resource in the most part of times, I'll join only the  `networkresource` table, by example.

So, I was wondering how can I do that.

I already tried something like:

```
SELECT c FROM URL c LEFT JOIN c.resource r where r.resourceType = 1 and r.url = :ip
```

But I got compilation errors when I add the `r.resourceType = 1`.

So, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to say by `c.resource` in your query? `c` is a `URL`, and `URL` has no attribute called `resource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a bit of an assumption about what you're trying to do, i think you just want:

```
select c from URL c where c.url = :ip
```

Hibernate will take care of adding the join and the restriction on the discriminator. That's pretty much what Hibernate is for.